# Pip - Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I was installing pandas in pip using `sudo pip install pandas` and this huge error happened.

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-n5twe_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil'")]
```

Just before I installed pip through curl and I had to update packages that wouldn't uninstall if that's of any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're getting an `Operation not permitted` error which means pip is trying to install these packages in areas of the filesystem it is not allowed to it. I imagine you're running an OS X version that has System Integrity Protection.

You can read more about SIP [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899).

Have you tried `pip install --user pandas`?

Comment: You're my lord and savior, though does this means I did something wrong in the past and shouldn't have messed with my system files?